# Why does a conjuction like “à moins que” take the subjunctive even though it expresses conditions?

Tags: conjonctions, subjonctif, conditionnel, mode-grammatical, indicatif

Why isn't the indicative used after “à moins que”, if the action we are talking about has a great percentage of happening, or the imparfait, if the action is a bit far-fetched, and if they can be used what will be the difference in meaning?

I also wonder why a conjunction like *although* is used with the subjunctive. 
In a sentence like this, for example, I have no idea why there can be any uncertainty or emotions involved in order to use the subjunctive

> *Quoiqu*'il *fasse* froid, ils se promènent dans la forêt.

Answer (score 1):

***À moins que*** is introducing an hypothetical fact, so the subjunctive is used.

***Quoique*** is introducing a real fact, but this fact is breaking the logic of the main statement.

This is called a concessive statement. Depending on what conjunction is used, concessive statement require either the subjunctive or the indicative/conditional in French.

Subjunctive (the conjunction clearly introduces a concession):

- *Bien qu'**il fasse**/**ait fait**/**fît**/**eût fait** froid,...*
- *Encore qu'**il fasse**/... froid,...*
- ***Quoiqu***'**il fasse**/... froid,...
- *Malgré le fait qu'**il fasse**/... froid,...*
- *Sans qu'**il fasse** froid,...*

Indicative/Conditional (the conjunction introduces a softer concession, or no concession at all for the last case, all are more observations) :

- *Alors qu'**il faisait**/**fait**/**fera**/**ferait**/**aurait fait**/... froid,...*
- *Alors même qu'**il faisait**/**fait**/... froid,...*
- *Tandis qu'**il faisait**/**fait**/... froid,...*
- *Pendant qu'il **faisait**/**fait**/... froid,...*

Where there is no concession but a logical cause, the indicative or conditional is expected too:

- Puisqu'il **faisait/fait/fera/ferait/**... froid,...
- Parce qu'il **faisait/fait/fera/ferait/**... froid,...

There is also the controversial ***malgré que*** which should require the subjunctive but which is more often followed by the indicative in relaxed colloquial spoken French:

- *Malgré qu'il **fait** froid,...*

Comment: But doesn't à moins que means unless ? I mean if it means unless then it should be an if clause and the imparfait should also be used to introduce an hypothetical thought

Comment: And in my question, I'm sorry, I just got a little confused and wrote: _....action we are talking about has a great percentage of happening, or **conditional** if the action is a bit far-fetched.._ when I actually meant _imparfait_ , I've just edited it.